# Intersecting circles and the sine and cosine rules

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I wrote a question using three numbers $r_1$, $r_2$ and $l$. I am struggling to solve it "in general" while playing by certain rules. The rules are: no calculator and no half- or double-angle formulae. (The rules are necessary because they mimic the world of my students!) The question is meant to be on the cosine (and sine) rules.

> **Question.** Two circles with centres $c_1$ and $c_2$ of radius $r_1=2\operatorname{cm}$ and $r_2=4\operatorname{cm}$ have their centres $l=5\operatorname{cm}$ apart. The circles meet at the points $p$ and $q$ (so the segments $c_1p$ and $c_1q$ have length $r_1$ while $c_2p$ and $c_2q$ have length $r_2$). Denote by $\theta_1$ the angle between $c_1p$ and $c_1q$, and denote by $\theta_2$ the angle between $c_2p$ and $c_2q$.
>
> Find $\cos\theta_1$ and $\cos\theta_2$.

I picked the values $r_1=2\operatorname{cm}$, $r_2=4\operatorname{cm}$ and $l=5\operatorname{cm}$ almost at random. Note that if these are chosen carefully the question becomes much more tractable (for example, $r_1=2\operatorname{cm}$, $r_2=\sqrt2\operatorname{cm}$and $l=1+\sqrt3\operatorname{cm}$).

Comment: Why not ask for $\angle PC_1C_2$ and $\angle PC_2C_1$?

Comment: That is, use cosine law to find $\angle PC_1C_2$ first  and then find the cosine (double that of $\angle PC_1C_2$).

Comment: @almagest Because that is too simple!

Comment: @Mick How would you do that without using a half- or double-angle formulae?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By cosine formula, $\alpha$ can be found from the given 2, 4, 5.

Since the two triangles are congruent, $\beta = \alpha$.

∴ $\theta_1 = \alpha + \beta = 2 \times \alpha$.

Then, $\cos \theta_1$ is found by calculating  its equivalent, $\cos (2 \times \alpha)$, which should not be considered as a double angle formula.

$\cos \theta_2$ can be treated in the similar fashion.

---

Edit: Second method

By Pythagoras theorem, we have $x^2 + (5 – x)^2 = 4^2 – x ^2$, we get $5 – x = 1.3$

Then $\cos \alpha = 0.65$ and $\alpha = 49.4584….$

I don’t think one can obtain the last result without using calculator.

[image]

Comment: How do you find $\alpha$ though? This requires a calculator (in general).

Comment: @user1729 Sorry that I missed the no calculator part of your requirement.   I have just added a second method. However, it still need a calculator in the very last part. ... Do you mean we can choose any arrangements of r1, r2 and L?

Comment: continue.... so that $\cos \alpha$ (or $\cos (2 \alpha)$) ends up as some surd involving fraction?

Comment: Yeah, using similar logic to finding $\sin\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ if you are given that $\cos\theta=12/13$ with $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$. (Then $\sin\theta=5/13$ and $\tan\theta=5/12$.)

Comment: @user1729 If that is the case, your example can have the job done already. See my second post.

Answer (score 0):

let the center line $c_1c_2$ cut the bigger circle at $a$ and the smaller circle at $b.$  from the isoscles triangles $c_2pa, c_1pb,$ you can show that $pa=pb = x(say)$ now use the cosine rule(or stewarts theorem) to show that $x = \sqrt 2.$ once you have that you can find that $\frac12 pq = \sqrt{x^2 - (\frac12) ^2} = \frac{\sqrt 7}2.$ now use use the cosine rule on the isocles triangle $c_1pq$ with sides $2,2$ and $\sqrt 7$ to find the $\angle pc_1 q.$

Comment: I do not understand why $pa=pb$ (and I think it is wrong in general). For example, using the easier $\sqrt2$, $2$ and $1+\sqrt3$ values I mentioned in the question gives $(pa)^2=8-2\sqrt3$ while $(pb)^2=4-\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

I use the $"5-12-13"$ special angled triangle as illustration. We intentionally choose $C_1P = 13, C_2P = 2 \sqrt 5$ and then $C_1C_2 = 12 +5$. Thus, $C_1PY$ formed the said triangle.

[image]

Construct (1) $YH \bot CP$; and (2) $e$, the perpendicular bisector of $C_1P$. ….

It should be clear that all green marked angles are equal and some triangles are similar. This means $a = \dfrac {5 \times 5}{13}$ and $XZ = 6.5  -  \dfrac {25}{13} = h$, say

In $\triangle XYZ, XY = \dfrac {13h}{12} = k$, say

In $\triangle PXY, PX = \sqrt {5^2 + k^2} = j$. say. Therefore $\cos \angle PXY = \cos (2\theta) = \dfrac {k}{j}$.

I hope your students know the method of finding $j$, a number involving square roots, without using calculator.